# Dynamically serialize or deserialize properties in apex

Tags: apex, json, code, serialization

I want to have dynamic properties in my JSON structure, something like this -

```
{
    "payload":
    {
        "one":
        {
            "x": 1
        },
        "two":
        {
            "x": 2
        },
        "three":
        {
            "x": 3
        }
    }
}
```

where "one", "two", "three" will be dynamic values. Does Salesforce support way to handle such JSONs for serialization or deserialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

**1) Using the [JSON generator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm), build/parse the string manually.**

**2) Use `JSON.serialize()` and `JSON.deserializeUntyped()` methods**

To serialize you can use a `Map <String, Object>`:

```
Map <String, Object> test = new Map <String, Object> {
    'payload' => new Map <String, Object> {
        'one' => new Map <String, Object> {
            'x' => 1
        },
        'two' => new Map <String, Object> {
            'x' => 2
        },
        'three' => new Map <String, Object> {
            'x' => 3
        }
    }
};

system.debug(JSON.serialize(test));
```

To deserialize, similar principle:

```
String jsonString = '{'+
'    \"payload\":'+
'    {'+
'        \"one\":'+
'        {'+
'            \"x\": 1'+
'        },'+
'        \"two\":'+
'        {'+
'            \"x\": 2'+
'        },'+
'        \"three\":'+
'        {'+
'            \"x\": 3'+
'        }'+
'    }'+
'}';

Map <String, Object> result = (Map <String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
Map <String, Object> payload = (Map <String, Object>) result.get('payload');
Map <String, Object> objectTwo = (Map <String, Object>) payload.get('two');
system.debug(objectTwo.get('x')); // result = 2
```

**Bonus:**
Check out the [json2apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) app.

Comment: I think this is the correct approach, but was thinking more on implementing this on an existing structure. but really liked your answer here.!! Thanks

Comment: By "existing structure" do you mean a wrapper class? If that's the case then it will only work for static JSON structures. As long as there is something dynamic (apart from a list object), then you've gotta do one of the above.